# Get Buffer from Graphic Interface GDI+

Tags: c++, graphics, mfc, gdi+

Here is my code :

```
void CPictureCtrl::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
if (mBIsPicLoaded)  {
    RECT rc;
    this->GetClientRect(&rc);
    INT width = (INT) rc.right - rc.left;
    INT height = (INT)(rc.bottom - rc.top);

    Graphics graphics(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
    Image image(mPstream);
    graphics.DrawImage(&image, (INT)rc.left, (INT)rc.top, width, height);
}
```

Is it possible to extract the  buffer from graphics because the picture has been scaled and I would like to have it as base64 ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain exactly what it is you want to do?  What is the end result you're looking for?

Comment: I just want to get the byte buffer from Graphics object after DrawImage.